# Hibernate Criterias - Agrupar Datas

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate, criteria

Atualmente eu consigo agrupar datas utilizando Projections.sqlGroupProjection().
Quando meu campo data está na mesma classe que eu crio o Criteria, funciona perfeitamente.
O Problema está quando eu crio um alias, e o campo data que eu quero agrupar está dentro da classe deste alias. Dentro do meu sqlGroupProjection ele não reconhece os alias que o hibernate da as classes.

Alguem tem alguma ideia de como contornar esta situação ou outra forma de agrupar datas sem utilizar a função "Extract"?

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei a solução aqui: http://www.dclick.com.br/2007/11/14/implementando-criterion-para-utilizar-extract-do-oracle/

No exemplo diz Oracle, mas funcionou no postgreSQL também.